# CSS in Weebly. Can't get menu to center

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav, weebly

I'm usually pretty good at solving this, but my usual methods aren't working here. Friend of mine asked me to try to fix the CSS here (http://www.latheaterfestival.com/) and the menu ul just isn't centering. Tried 100% width, margin: 0 auto; text-align: center....nothing will budge. Here's the menu HTML (condensed a bit):

```
<div class="nav-container"><ul class='wsite-menu-default'><li id='active'><a href='/index.html'>Home</a></li><li id='pg440106722136607103'><a href='/about.html'>About</a></li></ul></div>
```

and here's the CSS Weebly spews out:

```
#nav-wrap .nav-container { float:center; position:relative; left:-50%; text-align:left; margin-top:10px; z-index:2; }
#nav-wrap .nav-container ul{ list-style:none; position:relative; left:50%; z-index:2; }
#nav-wrap .nav-container li{float:center;position:relative;}
#nav-wrap .nav-container a{ text-decoration:none; font:600 12px 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif; text-transform:uppercase; margin:10px 15px; float:left; color:#666; letter-spacing:2px; padding:1px 2px; text-align:center; white-space:nowrap; }
#nav-wrap .nav-container a:hover{border-bottom:1px dashed #666;}
#nav-wrap .nav-container li#active a {border-bottom:1px solid #888;}
#nav-wrap .nav-container a:active{padding:2px 2px 0px;}
#nav-wrap {overflow:hidden}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use float and position relative, use display: inline-block. Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvu253vn/)

```
#nav-wrap .nav-container
{
    margin-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 2;
}
#nav-wrap .nav-container ul
{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
#nav-wrap .nav-container li
{
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav-wrap .nav-container a
{
    color: #666;
    float: left;
    font: 600 12px 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    padding: 1px 2px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#nav-wrap .nav-container a:hover
{
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #666;
}
#nav-wrap .nav-container li#active a
{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
}
#nav-wrap .nav-container a:active
{
    padding: 2px 2px 0px;
}
#nav-wrap
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```